# Are There Any Significant Changes in Localization Features Between VS2005/.NET 2.0, and VS2008/.NET 3.5?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, localization

We have a non-localized WebForms app written in VS2005/.NET 2.0, and are looking to localize it.

Are there any significant changes between .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 in the area of localization (either framework features or Visual Studio tools) that would make it worthwhile for us to upgrade the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nothing new. Resources and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Beta 1): What is New in Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd890508.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, much as I might want to move to .NET 4, that's probably too new. Many thanks for the info however.